# How to limit the advertising range of a beacon?

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Is it possible to limit the ranging of the beacon, so that only devices within a certain close range(or proximity) can identify and connect to the beacon? Lets say for example the devices outside 0.5 meter zone shouldn't be able to see or connect to the beacon. I am using a iOS device as a beacon. In the Apple's `CoreLocation` API, there is a method called [peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLBeaconRegion/peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower%3a) in the [CLBeaconRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html) class which says:

> **peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:**
>   Retrieves data that can be used to advertise the current device as a beacon.
>
> (NSMutableDictionary *)peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:(NSNumber *)measuredPower
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **measuredPower**:
>     The received signal strength indicator (RSSI) value (measured in decibels) for the device. This value represents the measured strength of the beacon from one meter away and is used during ranging. Specify `nil` to use the default value for the device.

Can this be used to limit the range of beacon? If yes, I am unable to understand how to decide the value to set for `measurePower` parameter? What are they trying to say by `...value represents the measured strength of the beacon from one meter away..`?

Please forgive if this is a very basic question. I've recently started iOS development and will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to adjust the range of an iBeacon without special hardware.

1. The power field that you mention is simply a calibration value transmitted by an iBeacon.  It doesn't affect the actual physical radio range of the iBeacon.  **If the transmitter can be seen by an iPhone 50 meters away, altering the power field value will not change this at all.**  The only thing it does is change is the calibration constant which is an input to the distance estimation algorithm (used for the accuracy and proximity fields) inside the iOS software.  Altering the power field will affect the estimated distance returned by the API, but it won't change the actual distance at which the iBeacon is first detected.
2. **Altering the transmit power of a standard bluetooth iBeacon is practically impossible**.  In theory you can use metal shielding to construct a "faraday cage" around the transmitter to mute its power, but my experience is that it isn't very effective and it is highly susceptible to tiny imperfections in the shielding.  If you want to change the transmit power you have to have somebody build you custom hardware.

The software alternative is to use the ranging API  to track an iBeacon while it is visible, and only perform an action when the estimated distance is close enough, say 0.5 meters as you suggest.  This works great -- only in the foreground.

If you require actually waking up your app in the background at a close range, this won't work.  The best you can do is have the monitoring API wake up your app when the iBeacon is first detected, and then send a notification to the user and start ranging.  If the user elects to bring the app to the foreground (at 50 meters) you can keep monitoring and then perform your desired action at 0.5 meters.  If the user does not elect to bring the app to the foreground, iOS will only give you about 5 seconds of time to continue ranging before it suspends your app.  It is very unlikely that the distance will change from 50 meters to 0.5 meters in this time.

Comment: This confirms everything I've seen/experienced thus far with iBeacons. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3):

With most BLE chips I've investigated, there are usually at least four settings for transmission power level that can be used to limit the advertising range.

The Texas Instruments CC2541 (as used in their SensorTag development device) and CC2540 have +4, 0, -6, and -23 as their power level options. However, changing that in the SensorTag does require a recompile of the firmware. As-is, the provided firmware mentions the power level in only one place, but that is just a value that is broadcasted to inform any central listener how loud the beacon is—so that the central device can better calculate an estimated range based on received signal strength (RSSI). An additional line must be added to the firmware to actually change the transmission power. For example:

```
HCI_EXT_SetTxPowerCmd( HCI_EXT_TX_POWER_0_DBM );
```

Based on this, there should be two places on an iOS device where you can set the power level: one that just informs the listeners what the level is, and one where the BLE chip's true transmission power is actually changed. However, expect these values to be restricted to only a few enumerated choices which may or may not meet your real-world range needs.

(The SensorTag's -23 setting would probably do well for a 0.5 meter detection range. But if you want the SensorTag to always be advertising, it will require an [additional firmware change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090954/how-to-modify-the-ti-sensortag-firmware-to-advertise-indefinitely/22090955#22090955).)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked to see if the `proximity` property was helpful? [From the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeacon_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLBeacon/accuracy):

CLProximity
Constants that reflect the relative distance to a beacon.

```
typedef {
   CLProximityUnknown,
   CLProximityImmediate,
   CLProximityNear,
   CLProximityFar
} CLProximity;
```

I would also experiment trying to combine the the `proximity` with `accuracy` and `rssi`.

Comment: Yes Ravi I did. But that's for the central device, isn't it ? Even if used in peripheral device, it will only give the relative distance between the two as per my understanding of demo apps. I also tested both the parameters. It will help when my central device is receiving the signals but filters it based on Rssi or accuracy values. It does not limit the broadcast signal range of the peripheral device.  If you've understood that it does limit, then please do explain. I've been searching and wondering about the same for long time. Thanks again :)

Comment: You cannot really limit the range against *some other* detector, but you can configure your *intended* receiver *app* to only pay attention to signal which are stronger than some level - something which correlates *crudely* to distance (many other factors play a role as well).  If you want some beacons to have a different effective range with the same app than others, you can probably do that by adjusting the actual vs claimed transmit power (as encoded in the packet), which the receiver needs in order to attempt to guess range from received strength.

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna vary from beacon to beacon. If you use beacons from Radius Networks, they have a transmit power setting that lets you essentially limit the ability of the beacon radio to broadcast to long ranges. I don't know if other brands have it, but most do not from what I've seen.