# How to Update the TI SensorTags to increase outcomes of accelerometer and Gyroscope on per second time intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

Hi I am using TI sensor tag i want to draw path of moving sensors by using the values of accelerometer and gyroscope.
i have found Pitch and Roll by this equation:
 pitch  = (atan2(-ACy, ACz)*180.0)/M_PI;
 roll = (atan2(ACx, sqrt(ACy*ACy + ACz*ACz))*180.0)/M_PI;

But sensor is giving 3-4 data values per second of intervals but for accurate path drawing i need 20-30 values per second
Is there is any way to update the sensors or to update firmware of Sensor tags??

Comment: Hello @Gorav Grover update your  software from Ti app

Comment: Follow the answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090954/how-to-modify-the-ti-sensortag-firmware-to-advertise-indefinitely by @Mathijs to update the TI SensorTags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify the TI SensorTag Firmware to advertise indefinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090954/how-to-modify-the-ti-sensortag-firmware-to-advertise-indefinitely)

Answer (score 2):

Hello @Gorav Grover Please download multi tool application.It provide  option to upgrade your sensors.For updating you also required img/a and ing/B for your firmware.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the Sensrtag Project in IAR Embedded Workbench.

In the File **SensorTag.c**

you will see following **CONSTANTS** in the begining of the file

each of these constants set the update interval

```
// How often to perform sensor reads (milliseconds)
 #define TEMP_DEFAULT_PERIOD                   1000
 #define HUM_DEFAULT_PERIOD                    1000
 #define BAR_DEFAULT_PERIOD                    1000
 #define MAG_DEFAULT_PERIOD                    2000
 #define ACC_DEFAULT_PERIOD                    1000
 #define GYRO_DEFAULT_PERIOD                   1000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't gain access to IAR Embedded Workbench or doesn't want to deal with embedded programming, you can still use the Accelerometer Period characteristic (0xAA13) in the Accelerometer service and then perform a Write Characteristic of a byte value from 0 - 255 with your application. 100 is the default value (1 notification per second), and if you write the value 10, you will receive 10 notifications per second.

Comment: Beware: this value isn't the number of notification per second, but the period in multiple of 10ms