# How to modify the TI SensorTag (CC2650STK) Firmware to advertise indefinitely?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I need the SensorTag(CC2650STK) to advertise till it gets connected with a device. Earlier, I've modified SensorTag(CC2541) using the answer of this question ([How to modify the TI SensorTag Firmware to advertise indefinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090954/how-to-modify-the-ti-sensortag-firmware-to-advertise-indefinitely)) and I need to replicate the same with this SensorTag without using Debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SensorTag 2 CC2650 advertising indefinately firmware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042880/sensortag-2-cc2650-advertising-indefinately-firmware)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible from the App. It's very easy with the debug devpack, though:
https://store.ti.com/cc-devpack-debug.aspx

It's only $15 and you don't even need to install an IDE to modify the SensorTag code. You can use the cloud IDE on 
http://dev.ti.com/

It has the SensorTag code and lets you modify, compile and download. All you need to do is install the debug devpack driver when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042880/sensortag-2-cc2650-advertising-indefinately-firmware) which talks about how to set up the 2650 to advertise indefinitely (which you can do from the CCS or CCS Cloud).