# SensorTag 2 CC2650 advertising indefinately firmware

Tags: bluetooth, sensors

I want to use a SensorTag 2 so that it is sitting there broadcasting it's data (and, critically connectable over bluetooth) from when it's turned on to when\if I ever turn it off. Out of the box, the tag is set to only advertise over Bluetooth for a few mins which means that when the connection eventually fails or when the device connected to the tag boots etc etc you can't connect again without physically visiting the tag and resetting it.

I see there is firmware that the myWeatherCenter people have created that lets the tag work as a weather station by basically setting it to advertise indefinitely... frustratingly though their firmware is only the sensortag version 1 :-(

I've researched on and off for months and months now and nothing coming back.. suggesting either nobody else wants this, there is a really simple solution everyone one else knows about or ...? I can't even see anyone else asking this question really... which is worrying.
Does anyone have a firmware file that sets this setting for the sensortag 2 or know how to modify the firmware to set this setting?

Comment: Did you manage to compile and flash the changed firmware? Did it work as intended?

Comment: I haven't yet but hopefully will get there soon, family allowing, evenings are in short supply! The answer makes sense to have marked accepted and will add comments when done. Thank you for getting back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to change the SensorTag 2/CC2650 platform so that its behavior suits your use case. I - for example - currently use a custom firmware doing pre-processing of sensor readings on the SensorTag and sending data directly in the advertisement message indefinitely (of course you have to tweak intervals and payload to get a decent [battery life](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_bluetooth-ble/power_calculator.page)).

I assume you have CCS and the sources (SensorTagApp and SensorTagStack) at hand?

I recommend flashing the current SensorTagStack first, if not done yet (though I'm not yet on 2.2 myself).

In the `SensorTagApp` project under Application you find `SensorTag.c`. In there you should change:

```
#define DEFAULT_DISCOVERABLE_MODE             GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS_LIMITED
```

to

```
#define DEFAULT_DISCOVERABLE_MODE             GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS_GENERAL
```

This is the usual advise and might already do the trick.

In my firmware I also changed (in `SensorTag.c`, in the `SensorTag_init` function):

```
uint16_t advertOffTime = 0;
```

to

```
uint16_t advertOffTime = 1;
```

Please try these changes and get back to me. If that wasn't enough I will do a more thorough comparison of the stock firmware and my custom firmware. I also recommend the more specific [ti Bluetooth low energy forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_low_energy/f/538).

Comment: Great, thank you for that. I'll try and have a go tonight. I assume it's obvious how you compile and get the code onto the tag.. which may be my next challenge :-)

Comment: Code Composer is the recommended IDE from TI. There is a desktop application (Windows/Ubuntu) and the cloud version: https://dev.ti.com/. Best option for development is the rather cheap Debugger DevPack http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-devpack-debug#buy. Over-the-Air Download via iOS app should also work, with android I had problems with OAD (haven't tried it in a while though, since I'm using the DevPack).

Comment: Thanks for this @f-kelein, I didn't know about their cloud version. Can you elaborate on how you put more sensor data into the advertising packet? Or should I ask a second question here if it's a bit more detailed?

Comment: It is a bit much for the comment section (also ability to format is limited as a comment), so opening a new question and posting the link here  might be the better option. Answer might take up to a day though, because I don't have the code at hand for the next couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks @f-klein, asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995989/how-can-sensor-data-be-embedded-in-the-advertising-packet-of-the-ti-sensortag-cc

Answer (score 0):

You could find the workflow for a complete solution and the firmware for continuous advertising which I created recently, at [Sensortag CC2650STK Custom Firmware Modification&Download Workflow (Continuous Advertising)](https://github.com/PeakUp/TIDC-CC2650STK-SENSORTAG-Custom-Firmware-Continuous-Advertising-Broadcasting-) using Code Composer Studio, Debugger DevPack and Flash Programmer 2 software