# TI Sensortag change firmware to a higher update rate for sensor readings

Tags: javascript, c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to change the update rate for the gyroscope and acceleration readings in the Ti Sensortag CC2650 to a higher update rate than 10 Hz. I know, that it is possible to change the firmware as indicated bythis post: [How to modify the TI SensorTag Firmware to advertise indefinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090954/how-to-modify-the-ti-sensortag-firmware-to-advertise-indefinitely)
Can anyone help and tell me what to change?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards,

Niklas

EDIT: 
Ok, after the comment below, I have done some testing...

- I am using the easyble.js configuration provided by the evothings client. As soon as I change the MOVEMENT_PERIOD (UUID 'f000aa83-0451-4000-b000-000000000000') to a value smaller than 10 I get an "Unknown ATT error" and the streaming falls back to a default value. This also happens with the unchanged firmware of the CC2650 Sensortag. When changing the MOVEMENT_PERIOD to larger values, the update rate changes correctly (e.g. a value of 25 equals 250ms between readings).
- I have changed line 115 in the SensorTag.c Firmware to 32 (was 160), defining a DEFAULT_ADVERTISING_INTERVAL of 50Hz, compared to 10Hz in the default. Unfortunately this didn´t show any result.

Basically I am new to firmware programming and don´t know what to change to enable my app and SensorTag combination to measure with update rates higher than 10Hz. I would be very thankful for help!

Comment: Your question is way too broad, and doesn't show any research effort. What have actually done to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: I just edited the post and hope it is clearer now. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by reducing the value of SENSOR_DEFAULT_PERIOD. By default this is 1000 MS. Try reducing this value.