# Using hcitool to set ad packets

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, bluez, hci

There is a well known blog post going around on how to set a usb bluetooth 4 dongle to be an iBeacon. It boils down to this magical command:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The issue with this example is that it is so opaque it's hard to use it in any more general format. I've been able to break it apart a bit:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd
```

sends an hci command to the hci0 device

```
0x08 0x0008
```

is just magic to set the ad package, other stackoverflow commands have said "just use it, don't ask

```
1e
```

is the length of the ENTIRE following data packet in bytes

```
02 01 1a 1a
```

Are flags to set up the ad packet (details on request)

```
ff 4c 00 ...
```

is the 'company specific data' that encodes the iBeacon info

What I've tried to do is replace the "FF ..." bytes with the opcodes for setting the NAME parameter "04 09 41 42 43" (which should set it to ABC) but that doesn't work.

I'm surprised the hcitool doesn't give us some examples on how to set the ad packet as this would be very useful in setting all sorts of other params (like TEMP or POWER). Has anyone else had any experience in using hcitool to set things like NAME?

Comment: The advertising packet payload that ends up transmitted begins with the "02 01 1a 1a" sequence.  The "ff 4c" you are trying to change is thus well inside the payload, and so changing that will not result in a different command, but merely a garbled transmission.

Answer (score 8):

Late reply, but somebody might find this useful. I found it as I was looking around for solutions myself when using hcitool.

If you use `hcitool cmd --help` it will tell you something like this `cmd <ogf> <ocf> ...`. It helps to look at the [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) to find out what 0x08 and 0x0008 would be for OGF and OCF. Specifically Vol. 2, Part E, 7.8

> For the LE Controller Commands, the OGF code is defined as 0x08

and for the OCF of 0x0008

> Advertising_Data_Length, Advertising_Data

So basically, with 0x08 0x0008 you say you are setting (in the LE Controller) the length of the data that is sent. As for the name, since the length of the BLE advertisement packet is 31 bytes (1E), you need to send the whole 31 bytes. So if you only have ABC as the name, setting `04 09 41 42 43` is correct, but that's only five bytes. For 31 you need to add `00` 26 times. Just be careful you don't add too much or too little.

Also, I wasn't under the impression that BLE ad. packets are of fixed 31 byte size, but they are at least for hcitool. It doesn't work when you specifically set the outgoing size to something smaller than `1E`.

Answer (score 5):

No. None of this answers is correct and clean.
1) BLE have a separate command set. "LE Set Advertising Data" command must be used (see 7.8.7 vol 2 part E).
2) LE Set Advertising Data is much complex than what explained above. There are at least 2 1-octet length fields, packet must be 32 bytes length, zero padded, but the first length byte must not be 0x1e (31) but the length of the significant used part, containing one or more headers. Each header still contains a length, one AS Type byte (0x09 for set local name) and the name.

SET LE LOCAL NAME:

```
hciconfig hci0 down
hciconfig hci0 up
hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 0c 0b 09 6c 69 6e 6b 6d 6f 74 69 6f 6e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
hciconfig hci0 leadv 0
```

0x0c : length of the following group of headers
0x0b : length of this header
0x09 : AD Type for complete name
rest 0x0a length is the name

Comment: The order given above is incorrect. The hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 command must follow the hciconfig hci0 leadv 0 command. This is because leadv command also sets the advertising packaged data to default value of 0x000. So after calling "leadv" you need to call hctitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 .. command to reset the packaged data to your custom values

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148306/1461050) to a similar question.  It basically describes how you can download the giant [Bluetooth Core Spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) document, and read through all the commands that it offers you.  You can use the hcitool command to execute any of these commands if you can just figure out the right format (and figure out what the commands actually do!)

Major caveat:  I have not tried setting the name myself, but glancing at the spec, it looks like this is described on page 482 of the spec in section "7.3.11 Write Local Name Command".  According to this the command consists of:

```
OCF: 0x0013
Name (up to 248 bytes)
```

So I would try a command like this:

`hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0013 41 42 43`

One other tip:  When you issue commands like this, try running `hcidump &` so the command executes in the background.  Then, you can enter experimental `hcitool` commands (or even `hciconfig` commands) and see annotated details about what (human readable) commands executed and what errors occurred, if any.

Using the above tip, you can also try executing `hciconfig name abc` to set the local name using that command line tool, while you are executing a `hcidump &` in the background.  This should show you the proper hcitool command values to use.

Comment: Thanks David, I gave this a shot but I got back "Send failed: Operation not permitted". My guess is that there is a difference between BT3 and BT4 commands. For example it *can't* be up to 248 bytes as the ad packet only has 28 bytes of free space so there is a clear disconnect here.

Comment: Well, I don't think the local name is sent out in the advertisement packet., so its length restriction should not apply.

Comment: The response "Send failed: Operation not permitted" probably indicates that the Linux user used to execute the command doesn't have the rights to write to the BLE device.  Try `sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0013 41 42 43`

Comment: this seems to be on site 828 of the current 4.0 spec file.
However this is from my understanding not the LE name, but the BD/EDR name, aka bluetooth classic, this is not setting the complete local name or the shortend local name. qoute
The Write_Local_Name command provides the ability to modify the user-
friendly name for the BR/EDR Controller. See Section 6.23 on page 446.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear you need to use two commands rather than one. The iBeacon data is contained in the "LE Set Advertising Data" data and has been mentioned elsewhere in this post. To see a BLE friendly name you can use an additional command "LE Set Scan Response Data", this requires the receiver to scan your device (rather than passively read the advertising packet). So you can combine Angelo's example with [this one](https://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/adding-ibeacon-data) to set the device as an iBeacon and set the "friendly name" which is the Scan Response data

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 E2 0A 39 F4 73 F5 4B C4 A1 2F 17 D1 AD 07 A9 61 00 00 00 00 C8 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0009 0c 0b 09 6c 69 6e 6b 6d 6f 74 69 6f 6e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This worked for me using an Ubuntu box with a BLE dongle and then scanning for the beacon using this [android BLE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.alt236.btlescan&hl=en_GB) scanning app