# Where can I find linux os bluetooth hcitool commands

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

In Linux, the `hcitool` `command` has a sub-command `cmd` (`hcitool cmd hex....`)

**Question :**
Does anyone know where can I find the list for the commands available under `hcitool` `cmd`? and their co-responding `hexa`?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found what I need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144098/understanding-ibeacon-data-the-power-field-and-other-bytes/22148306#22148306) - it directs you the [bluetooth core specs,](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) and I found the information I was looking for there.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know the `HCI` commands are manufacturer defined.

Check the specification provided for your blueooth device, they should be defined there.